# I get "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern" How to solve this?

Tags: package-management, deb

I get "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern" How to  solve this?

I did the following things

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install libdigest-md5-file-perl deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install libdigest-md5-file-perl
```

when I tried to install libdigest-md5-file-perl it said libdigest-md5-file-perl is already the newest version

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error??

Comment: when I tried to run a script I get this error dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/hosts
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /proc/1976

Comment: What script? post it

Answer (score 4):

**Installation generated files** are a common cause for this error message, as mentioned at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159001/how-to-find-the-package-that-installed-a-comand-if-dpkg-s-finds-no-path-beca

For example, `/bin/nc` appears when you install the package `netcat-openbsd`.

But upon:

```
dpkg -S /bin/nc
```

we get `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/nc`.

This happens because `/bin/nc` is generated by the `update-alternatives` call in the [postinst script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/netcat-openbsd/trusty/view/head:/debian/netcat-openbsd.postinst) that gets run after installation.

It works like this because another version of `/bin/nc` is provided by the `netcat-traditional` package.

I don't think there is a general way of finding such generated files. In the specific case of alternative symlinks, we can just follow the link with `readlink -f`:

```
dpkg -S "$(readlink -f /bin/nc)"
```

Comment: Tip: `dpkg -S "$(readlink -f \`which nc\`)"` # don't need to know full path

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the package which actually provides these two `/etc/hosts`,`/proc/1976` files, then this error will appears.

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/hosts
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/hosts
$ dpkg -S /proc/1976
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /proc/1976
```

Because no package is intended to provide these two files.

IMO, you added the above two commands on your script so that the error appears.